# Application should give Indication while shut down

Tags: vb.net

I need to set my application to save entry (e.g LoggedOff) to database if application shuts down abnormally, like power failure or anything else like that.

What event should be fired to achieve this?

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can save such entry is by having external "monitor" on the web server that ping it on regular intervals (e.g. every 20 seconds) and if the web server does not respond flag it as down until it respond again.

That monitor can be for example windows service installed on different machine, or on some machines in case one goes down as well.

Answer (score 2):

If power have gone off, no events can be fired.